# In backbone.js how to update a view with new model data while maintaining the sorted order without a complete render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view in backbonejs bound to a sorted collection.

I want to periodically update the collection with new models but maintain the sorted order.

What is the best way to insert the new models in the view without completely rendering it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Collection.add](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add) when it fires the "add" event, passes an options hash which contains an "index" property, specifying where, if the collection is sorted via a comparator, the item is being inserted.

Using jQuery's nth-child selector, you can insert the item in the right place:

```
    $(function() {

        var ships = new Backbone.Collection();

        ships.comparator = function(ship) {
          return ship.get("name");
        };

        ships.on("add", function(ship, collection, options) {
            if (options.index === 0)
                $('ul#list').prepend("<li>Ahoy " + ship.get("name") + " at " + options.index + "!</li>");
            else
                $('ul#list li:nth-child('+ options.index +')').after("<li>Ahoy " + ship.get("name") + " at " + options.index + "!</li>");
        });

        ships.add([
            {name: "Flying Dutchman"},
            {name: "Black Pearl"}
        ]);

        ships.add({name: "Delaware"});

        ships.add({name: "Carolina"});

        ships.add({name: "America"});

    })
```

​
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/DRN4C/6/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the other answer (I believe it was an excellent answer, and this is just an addendum), but you should note that since version 0.9.9, the `options` hash will no longer include an `index` property. From the changelog:

> To improve the performance of add, options.index will no longer be set in the `add` event callback. `collection.indexOf(model)` can be used to retrieve the index of a model as necessary.

In the other answer, just replace `options.index` with `collection.indexOf(ship)`